# Finding two values of an expression

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

What are the smallest and largest possible values of the expression
$$\left(\frac{1}{a^2+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+1}+\frac{1}{c^2+1}\right)\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}+\frac{b^2}{b^2+1}+\frac{c^2}{c^2+1}\right),$$
when it is given that $ab+bc+ca=1$

My attempt:

By applying Cauchy on $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a^{2}+1},\quad\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2}{a^{2}+1}$$
we can say

$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a^{2}+1}\right)\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2}{a^{2}+1}\right)\ge{\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{a^{2}+1}\right)}^2,$$
and we can also see
$${\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{a^{2}+1}}={\sum_{cyc} a-\frac{a^{3}}{a^{2}+1}}\ge{\sum_{cyc} a - \frac{a^{2}}{2}}.$$
After this I am not able to proceed or do anything.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1906726p13049446

Comment: Next time, before asking on Math SE, use formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/search/ (as Martin R has probably done) : it is very efficient.

Comment: I am not able to understand the solution given on the website. They have written it very briefly. Please can anyone explain that solution?

Comment: Can you see how to rewrite this as $x(3-x)$ - which gives some clue as to how it might be solved

Comment: no sir please explain